# Escaping quotes in Angular with Freemarker Templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, freemarker

In a Freemarker template on a page with Angular, I have the following:

```
...
ng-init="somevariable = ${(model.usercontrolledstring)}"
...
```

I want to make sure this is hardened against XSS, so I've set up some escaping rules. However, the following value for `model.usercontrolledstring` causes JavaScript to execute:

```
abc&#39;+constructor.constructor(&#39;alert(1)&#39;)()+&#39;abc
```

The surprising thing is that when the client receives it, it arrives thusly:

```
ng-init="somevariable = 'abc&#39;+constructor.constructor(&#39;alert(1)&#39;)()+&#39;abc'"
```

So it looks like it's being escaped correctly, but Angular is still deciding to run it!

So I guess my questions would be:

1. What am I not understanding about Angular? (In particular, its decision to run after decoding html entities)
2. Is there a proper way of configuring a Freemarker Template to prevent this sort of XSS?

Comment: where are your "escaping rules"?

Comment: I'm using `freemarker.template.Configuration::setOutputFormat(HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE);`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use `somevariable = '${model.usercontrolledstring?jsString}'` there.

Also, if that thing goes into a `<script>` block, certainly you shouldn't apply HTML escaping there. It's not decoded by the browser inside `<script>`, so you end up with string values that literally contain `&#39;`. Unless the string meant to contain HTML as opposed to plain text, that's wrong.